# How to provide credentials to Fetch() and Pul() methods?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm looking for a nice clean example of how to do a pull using lidgit2sharp. I took the example here which does a fetch, but the reference to Credentials is throwing an exception.

```cs
using (var repo = new Repository(workingDir, null))
{
    Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes.Add("master", repoUrl);
    repo.Network.Fetch(remote, 
    {    
        Credentials credentials = new Credentials
        {
            Username = "username",
            Password = "password"
        }
    });
}
```

> The exception is Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or
>   interface 'LibGit2Sharp.Credentials'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's telling you in the error:  Credentials is an abstract class, interface, whatever.

Try this:

```
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
{

        Username = "username",
        Password = "password"
}
```

Comment: Yes! Worked! Thank you .... where the heck is that documented at? I looked everywhere.

Comment: @MightyUgh As far as I can tell... it's not really.  I found it through the power of IntelliSense.

Comment: There's a bit of **[documentation](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/aa94e9d9326e9318feb89e8c9f4300b0bf60f6ca/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TestHelpers/Constants.cs#L11-L23)** in the tests. This indeed may not be visible enough. If you feel like giving a hand, we'd happily merge a Pull Request improving this state ;-)

Comment: This API is obsolete, use [CredentialsProvider instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26177459/305092)