# LibGit2Sharp authentication in server side application

Tags: c#, git, authentication, service, libgit2sharp

I have a windows service, which should pull every 20 seconds all changes from a git server. What is the best way of authentication in this scenario, because i don't know how to work with username and password / ssl in service-side applications.

**EDIT**
I found here how to pass Username and password: [How to provide credentials to Fetch() and Pul() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23375239/2630261)

But i also want to deliver the public key for the client in my c# code.

Thank you!

Comment: *"But i also want to deliver the public key for the client in my c# code."* -> I'm not sure to understand this. Could you please elaborate on this topic? How does the public key come into play?

Comment: If i want to communicate with a git-server over ssl, i need my public key besides the username and password for authorization. But i don't now how to tell libgit2sharp were to find the key. Thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: @BendEg You don't have a public key with SSL...  Do you mean SSH?  Are you trying to authenticate with an SSH configuration?